# Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
@Dao
interface LectureDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun upsert(lecture: Lecture)

@Delete
fun delete(lecture: Lecture)

@Query("update lecture set attendanceCount = attendanceCount + 1")
fun incrementAttendance(lecture: Lecture)

@Query("select * from lecture")
fun getLectures(): LiveData<List<Lecture>>
}
```

Well, I have a problem when I write incrementAttendance function I got this error. What I'm trying to do is I want to increase the absentee status by 1 for a specific lesson. Here is my model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "lecture")
data class Lecture(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int?,
val lectureName: String?,
val attendanceCount: Int?
)
```

Why do I need TypeConverter for this? And how can I solve?

And I already tried to change kotlin-room versions. And that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by giving direct id instead of lecture class to parameter.

```
 @Query("update lecture set absenceCount = absenceCount + 1 where id = :id")
suspend fun incrementAbsenceCount(id: Int)
```